# replace function not working with list items

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace

I am trying to use the replace function to take items from a list and replace the fields below with their corresponding values, but no matter what I do, it only seems to work when it reaches the end of the range (on it's last possible value of i, it successfully replaces a substring, but before that it does not)

```
    for i in range(len(fieldNameList)):
        foo = fieldNameList[i]
        bar = fieldValueList[i]
        msg = msg.replace(foo, bar)
        print msg
```

This is what I get after running that code

```
<<name>> <<color>> <<age>>

<<name>> <<color>> <<age>>

<<name>> <<color>> 18
```

I've been stuck on this for way too long. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Full code:

```
def writeDocument():
    msgFile = raw_input("Name of file you would like to create or write to?: ")
    msgFile = open(msgFile, 'w+')
    msg = raw_input("\nType your message here. Indicate replaceable fields by surrounding them with \'<<>>\' Do not use spaces inside your fieldnames.\n\nYou can also create your fieldname list here. Write your first fieldname surrounded by <<>> followed by the value you'd like to assign, then repeat, separating everything by one space. Example: \"<<name>> ryan <<color>> blue\"\n\n")
    msg = msg.replace(' ', '\n')
    msgFile.write(msg)
    msgFile.close()
    print "\nDocument written successfully.\n"

def fillDocument():
    msgFile = raw_input("Name of file containing the message you'd like to fill?: ")
    fieldFile = raw_input("Name of file containing the fieldname list?: ")

    msgFile = open(msgFile, 'r+')
    fieldFile = open(fieldFile, 'r')

    fieldNameList = []
    fieldValueList = []
    fieldLine = fieldFile.readline()
    while fieldLine != '':
        fieldNameList.append(fieldLine)
        fieldLine = fieldFile.readline()
        fieldValueList.append(fieldLine)
        fieldLine = fieldFile.readline()

    print fieldNameList[0]
    print fieldValueList[0]
    print fieldNameList[1]
    print fieldValueList[1]
    msg = msgFile.readline()

    for i in range(len(fieldNameList)):
        foo = fieldNameList[i]
        bar = fieldValueList[i]
        msg = msg.replace(foo, bar)
        print msg

    msgFile.close()
    fieldFile.close()



###Program Starts#####--------------------

while True==True:
    objective = input("What would you like to do?\n1. Create a new document\n2. Fill in a document with fieldnames\n")
    if objective == 1:
        writeDocument()
    elif objective == 2:
        fillDocument()
    else:
        print "That's not a valid choice."
```

Message file:

```
<<name>> <<color>> <<age>>
```

Fieldname file:

```
<<name>>
ryan
<<color>>
blue
<<age>>
18
```

Comment: What is `msg` here?

Comment: We would appreciate a [MCVE]. Something we can run by copy pasting it, that showcases the error.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I added the full code and the text in the files being used with the script

Comment: You full code is *not* a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**

This is because all lines except the last line read from the "Fieldname" file contains "`\n`" characters. So when the program comes to the replacing part `fieldNameList` , `fieldValueList` and `msg` looks like this:

```
fieldNameList = ['<<name>>\n', '<<color>>\n', '<<age>>\n']
fieldValueList = ['ryan\n', 'blue\n', '18']
msg = '<<name>> <<color>> <<age>>\n'
```

so the replace() function actually searches for `'<<name>>\n'`,`'<<color>>\n'`,`'<<age>>\n'` in msg string and only `<<age>>` field get replaced.(You must have a "`\n`" at the end of msg file, otherwise it won't be replaced as well).

**Solution:**

use `rstrip()` method when reading lines to strip the newline character at the end.

```
fieldLine = fieldFile.readline().rstrip()
```

Comment: Using a debugger can save you a lot of time :)

Comment: How would i get a debugger?

Comment: Use an IDE like pycharm or spyder